# SQL Server 2012 Conccurent Inserts

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, nhibernate

I just want to ask, whats the best way of improving the performance of SQL Server, when there are multiple concurrent inserts in the same table. Currently I'm able to insert around 70k per second and want to improve that.

If it's important im using c# with NHibernate.

Comment: you can use bulk insertion .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Use bulk insert.** http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
2. **Remove all unnecessary indexes(remove all if possible) and foreign key constrains.** Each insert operation cause indexes reconstruction and constrains check.
3. **Set Recovery model to Simple.** Permits high-performance bulk copy operations.Reclaims log space to keep space requirements small. More precisely here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx
4. **Use NHibernate profiler to optimize performance in case of sophisticated logic**

Comment: this has the potential to be great answer if you just flesh out what all of these mean and why they would be good.

Comment: removing indexes and FK's? really?

Comment: We eventually end up with Hadoop. When you have a massive loads of data and lots of users the right approach is logical storage.